# VB.Net: Error when checking if Application is on first run

Tags: vb.net

I have a program which checks if it is running for the first time, or if it has run before.

This is the program code:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.FirstRun = True Then
        Me.Show()
    Else
        ValidateLicense.ShowDialog()
    End If


    My.Settings.FirstRun = False
    My.Settings.Save()
    My.Settings.Reload()
End Sub
```

For some odd reason, even when I tell Visual Studio to keep the start-up program CLOSED if it has run before, it still runs. Any help is much appreciated.

> Edit: I have added the 'FirstRun' properties to the settings already.
>   Edit: Added in the `Form1_Load` event.

Comment: Where in your program is this code?

Comment: I'm just writing the code I'm having issues with.

Comment: Is it in your form load event? Or called from there?

Comment: Yes, its in my FormLoad event.

Comment: Closing a form in its `Load` event handler is not a sensible thing to do.  The correct option here is to handle the `Startup` event of the application, which is raised before the startup form is even created. You can display your license dialogue there if appropriate and then you can set `e.Cancel` to `True` if you want to exit without displaying the startup form.

Comment: Ah, I was just about to make a couple of comments but just noticed you've changed the code.

Comment: You can just ignore the Form1 event, please write your solution. @video.baba

Comment: So how would I lay this code out @jmcilhinney what sub would I put it into? Or none?

Comment: Are you dealing with the 'My.Setting.FirstRun" in the ValidateLicense.ShowDialog()? If not you'll need to check again once it's closed.

Comment: Yes, I am dealing with it in the 'My.Settings.FirstRun'.

Comment: "what sub would I put it into". The one I said to, i.e. handle the Startup event of the application. Don't know how to do that? Good thing there are search engines then. I've pointed you in the right direction. You don't need to be led.

Comment: I've used this method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx but it still doesn't work. The normal startup Form still comes up. @jmcilhinney

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  Show us what you did, i.e. edit your question and add the new code and any other relevant information, and then we may be able to tell you what you did wrong.